# Xcode 7 Magical Record Unit Tests Fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

After upgrading from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7 (and now 7.0.1) my project crashes when starting unit tests. My iOS project is using Magical Record and the app crashes at this assertion:

```
    + (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_defaultContext
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSAssert(MagicalRecordDefaultContext != nil, @"Default context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?");
        return MagicalRecordDefaultContext;
    }
}
```

I've commented out all of my previous tests, and both of these tests show the same behavior:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface BadTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation BadTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testSanity {
    XCTAssert(1 == 1);
}

@end
```

and

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>

@interface BadTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation BadTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    NSLog(@"*** USING IN MEMORY STORE ***");
    [MagicalRecord setLoggingLevel:MagicalRecordLoggingLevelDebug];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testSanity {
    XCTAssert(1 == 1);
}

@end
```

Reverting back to Xcode 6 with the same tests resolves the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, with the same code. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Which version of MR are you using? I've encountered the same issue with 2.2 but haven't yet tested with 2.3

Comment: I'm using 2.3.0 installed via CocoaPods. Could this be caused by not linking the tests against something that MR is looking for?

Comment: What's the rest of the call stack?

Comment: still no solution to this? I'm facing the same :(

Comment: any resolution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up resolving the issue by adjusting my Podfile:

```
link_with 'TestApp', 'TestAppTests', 'TestAppUITests'

platform :iOS, '8.1'

target 'TestApp' do
     pod 'MagicalRecord'
end

target 'TestApp' do
     pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end
```

Previously my pod file just looked like this:

```
platform :iOS, '8.1'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation can stem from the presence of old runtime environment as mentioned in the release notes:

> Xcode processes may quit unexpectedly if older iOS Simulator runtimes
>   (Xcode 6.x) are present on disk

To check whether this is the cause, you can delete all old runtime libraries from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Comment: No Xcode processes are unexpectedly quitting from what I can tell. The issue seems to be with Magical Record. I removed all of the old runtime libraries from that directory and got the same results.